# sys_execve system call from Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, system-calls

asm_execve.s:

```
.section .data
file_to_run:
.ascii       "/bin/sh"

.section .text
.globl main

main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $0x8, %esp         # array of two pointers. array[0] = file_to_run  array[1] = 0

    movl file_to_run, %edi
    movl %edi, -0x4(%ebp)   
    movl $0, -0x8(%ebp)

    movl $11, %eax                      # sys_execve
    movl file_to_run, %ebx              # file to execute       
    leal -4(%ebp), %ecx                 # command line parameters
    movl $0, %edx                       # environment block
    int  $0x80              

    leave
    ret
```

makefile:

```
NAME = asm_execve
$(NAME) : $(NAME).s
    gcc -o $(NAME) $(NAME).s
```

Program is executed, but sys_execve is not called:

```
alex@alex32:~/project$ make
gcc -o asm_execve asm_execve.s
alex@alex32:~/project$ ./asm_execve 
alex@alex32:~/project$
```

Expected output is:

```
alex@alex32:~/project$ ./asm_execve 
$ exit
alex@alex32:~/project$
```

This Assembly program is supposed to work like the following C code:

```
char *data[2];
data[0] = "/bin/sh"; 
data[1] = NULL;
execve(data[0], data, NULL);
```

Something wrong in system call parameters?

Comment: Use `strace -e execve` to trace the execve call your program *actually* makes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `execve` system call *is* being called, but you are indeed passing it bad parameters.

(You can see this by running your executable using [`strace`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace).)

There are three problems:

1. `.ascii` does not 0-terminate the string.  (You might get lucky, as there is nothing following it in your `.data` section in this example, but that's not guaranteed...)  Add a 0, or use `.asciz` (or `.string`) instead.
2. `movl file_to_run, %edi` moves the value *pointed to* by the `file_to_run` symbol into `%edi`, i.e. the first 4 bytes of the string (`0x6e69622f`).  The *address* of the string is just the value of the symbol itself, so you need to use the `$` prefix for literal values: `movl $file_to_run, %edi`.  Similarly, you need to say `movl $file_to_run, %ebx` a few lines further down.  (This is a common source of confusion between AT&T syntax and Intel syntax!)
3. The parameters are placed on the stack in the wrong order: `-0x8(%ebp)` is a lower address than `-0x4(%ebp)`.  So the address of the command string should be written to `-0x8(%ebp)`, the 0 should be written to `-0x4(%ebp)`, and the `leal` instruction should be `leal -8(%ebp), %ecx`.

---

Fixed code:

```
.section .data
file_to_run:
.asciz       "/bin/sh"

.section .text
.globl main

main:
    pushl %ebp
    movl %esp, %ebp
    subl $0x8, %esp         # array of two pointers. array[0] = file_to_run  array[1] = 0

    movl $file_to_run, %edi
    movl %edi, -0x8(%ebp)   
    movl $0, -0x4(%ebp)

    movl $11, %eax                      # sys_execve
    movl $file_to_run, %ebx              # file to execute       
    leal -8(%ebp), %ecx                 # command line parameters
    movl $0, %edx                       # environment block
    int  $0x80              

    leave
    ret
```

Comment: As a non-portable extension, Linux allows `argv` or `envp` to actually *be* NULL (like you're doing for envp), so `xor %ecx,%ecx` ; `xor %edx,%edx`.  An easier way to create `argv[]` on the stack would be `mov $file_to_run, %ebx`;  `push $0` (or a zeroed reg); `push %ebx`; `mov %esp, %ecx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes non-portable? We are at the assembly level, what portability could we have here?

Comment: @Ruslan: Exactly; there's no downside to taking advantage if you're writing in asm, because there's no reason to expect this non-standard behaviour to change on Linux.  The [`execve(2)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html#NOTES) documenting this is talking about C, where it is non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't need to load anything in the other arguments. If you are doing this in x86 the following simpler code will also work:

```
.global _main
.section .text

.data
file_to_run:
.asciz "/bin/sh"

.section .text
.globl main

_main:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp

movl $11, %eax                      # sys_execve
movl $file_to_run, %ebx              # file to execute       
movl $0, %ecx                       # Null value will work too
movl $0, %edx                       # Null will works too
int  $0x80              

leave
ret
```

This will essentially open a shell terminal after invoking the system call.

Comment: You should use `xor %ecx,%ecx` to zero registers.  Are you sure that passing non-zero garbage works?  Anything other than `0` (or a valid pointer) should make the system call return `-EFAULT`.  NULL pointers for `argv` and `envp` are specially documented as Linux-specific behaviour (http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), and being equivalent to passing a *pointer to* a NULL pointer.  But that doesn't imply that other bad pointers will "work".  That would actually be a bug in the implementation if it went and execed something instead of returning `-EFAULT` with non-0 bad pointers

Comment: Yes you are correct. I am sorry about that. I basically meant that you if you wish to open a terminal, you don't need to give any specific arguments and it will still work if you give in null values.

Comment: Are you sure you tested this?  You need `$file_to_run`, otherwise you're just loading the first 4 bytes of the string and passing it as a pointer.  Also, you save/restore `ebp`, but your code clobbers `ebx`.  If you want to return safely instead of crashing when `execve` returns an error instead of execcing, you should `push/pop` ebx as well / instead of making a stack frame.  (Perhaps the CRT code is ok if you clobber ebx though.)  Optional improvements: your string can go in `.rodata` so you don't need a `.data` section.  You can use `.asciiz` to get a zero-terminated string.