# execvp usage on nasm

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, cpu-registers, execve

I'm learning NASM now, linux system calls probably. I'm trying to copy a process and call linux utility, but have same troubles with execvp, I don't know how to pass arguments into it. How I can do this right?

```
SECTION .data
    cmd_cat: db '/bin/cat', 0
    arg_cat: db 'log.txt', 0
    cat: dd cmd_cat, arg_cat, 0

     fd1: dw 0, 0
     pipe_error_message: db 'pipe error occured', 0xa
     pipe_error_message_length: equ $ - pipe_error_message

     fork_error_message: db 'fork error occured', 0xa
     fork_error_message_length: equ $ - fork_error_message
SECTION .text
GLOBAL _start:
_start:
     ;call pipe(fd1)
     ;42 - pipe system call number
     mov eax, 42
     mov ebx, fd1

     ;call kernel to execute
     int 080h
     cmp eax, 0
     jne pipe_error


     ;call pipe(fd2)
      mov eax, 42
      mov ebx, fd1
      int 080h
      cmp eax, 0
      jne pipe_error

      ;fork()
      mov eax, 2
      int 080h
      cmp eax, -1
      je fork_error
      jnz child_cat 
      call exit

 ;displays error message and finishes the programm when something is wrong with pipe
 pipe_error:
     mov edx, pipe_error_message_length
     mov ecx, pipe_error_message
     call sys_write
     call exit

 ;displays error message and finishes the programm when something is wrong with fork
 fork_error:
      mov edx, fork_error_message_length
      mov ecx, fork_error_message
      call sys_write
      call exit

 ;sys_write(unsigned int fd, const char __user *buf, size_t count);
 sys_write:
      mov ebx, 1               
      mov eax, 4               
      int 080h


 ;exit(0)
 exit: 
      mov  eax,1
      mov  ebx,0
      int 080h

 child_cat:
      mov ebx, [fd1]
      mov eax, 6
      int 080h

      ;dup2(fds[1],1)
      mov ecx, 1
      mov ebx, [fds + 4]
      mov eax, 63
      int 080h

      mov eax, 11
      mov ebx, cmd_cat
      mov ecx, cat
      int 080h
```

Comment: The execve system call (eax = 0xb) will run a file, looking for a pointer to a filename (null-terminated string) in ebx, a pointer to an array of pointers to arguments in ecx, and a pointer to an array of pointers to environment variables in edx.  Each of the arrays must be terminated by a null pointer, and each other element is a pointer to a null-terminated string (argument or environment variable, as the case may be).  (More [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and [here](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)).  Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I don't know how to declare them(arrays of pointers) in NASM. Do you know how to do that or maybe some documentation?

Comment: Previous answer [**sys_execve system call from Assembly**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342410/sys-execve-system-call-from-assembly)

Comment: On an x86 system, the size of a pointer is 4 bytes. To declare an array in the .data section of 4-byte storage initialized to NUL, use: `nameofptr times N dd 0`. (where `N` is the number of pointers you want). It is the same as `nameofptr dd 0,0,0,0,0.....` See section 3.2.5 of the NASM manual.

Comment: Zero-terminate your strings! Then `array dd arg_cat, cmd_cat, 0`

Comment: Thanks Frank, now it works! Another question how to close pipe in NASM, because when I call sys close I'm getting segmentation fault

Comment: I think sys_close should be okay, but `fd1: dw 0, 0` probably needs to be `dd`. After sys_fork, we're "in two places at once". If `eax` is zero, we're the child, if `eax` is the PID of the child, we're the parent, and probably want to sys_wait on the child's PID(?). If error, `eax` will be -ERRNO - not -1 exactly (man page describes the C wrapper, not the system call). I think you're ending up at `child_cat:` in both parent and child. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me in the gas assembler.  I have explained what it does, so hopefully someone else can provide the nasm translation.

```
.text

    .global _start

_start:

    movl $0xb, %eax          # system call 0xb (execve) goes in eax

    movl $arg0, %ebx         # put the _address_ of the command string 
                             # in ebx (we are providing a pointer)

    movl $ptrarray, %ecx     # put the _address_ of the array of pointers 
                             # to arguments in ecx (again, a pointer)

    movl $0, %edx            # put a literal zero in edx (we don't have 
                             # environment variables to pass, so we give
                             # a null pointer)

    int $0x80                # run the system call

.data


ptrarray:                    # This is the array of pointers to command line 
                             # arguments
    .long arg0, arg1, 0      # The first element is a _pointer_ to the command 
                             # The second element is a _pointer_ to an argument
                             # The third is a null pointer to indicate no more

arg0:                        # This is the command string
    .asciz "/bin/cat"
arg1:                        # This is the argument string
    .asciz "file.txt"
```