# Ubuntu 16.04 assembly code for shell

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, shellcode

```
.global main
main:
    call func
    .string "/bin/sh"
func:
    push %rsp
    pop %rsi
    pop %rdi
    mov $0x00, %edx
    mov $0x3b, %eax
    syscall
```

I wrote assembly lagunage like above for execute /bin/sh
I compiled it but when I try to execute program, `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open ????` this error is occur.
It doesn't execute /bin/sh. I want to know why I can't execute /bin/sh

> I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and x64 Architectures

Comment: An alternative is to use `system` function which call external program. take a look at [this](https://godbolt.org/g/jN057x) to view assembler example

Comment: But I heard that `system` function also use `execve` in it's internal function call. So I want to use `execve`

Comment: Exact, `system` will call `execve`, but it is a little more complicated that you think. calling `system` is easier. Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9342410/sys-execve-system-call-from-assembly) for `execve`

Comment: Are you attempting to write shell code for exploitation reasons? I ask to verify the rationale for this kind of code.

Comment: Yes. I just want to study how to make shell code. Most reference in internet was executing `/bin/sh` so I tried it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is needlessly hard to follow because of using push/pop in a weird way, but running your program under `strace -f ./a.out` to trace the system calls shows:

```
... dynamic linker and libc init stuff before main() is called ...
execve("/bin/sh", ["/bin/sh", "\211\307\350\t\222\1", "\367", "\367", 0x100000000, "\350\10"], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So on my system, `execve` returns with an error, but the program exits successfully.  IDK how you're getting `/bin/sh: 0: Can't open ????`.  Your question doesn't contain enough information to reproduce your results.  But maybe when you tried, the stack happened to contain different garbage.  I built it with `gcc -g foo.S`.

After `main` fails to return, execution falls through into whatever CRT function follows `main`, which does end with a RET instruction.  It must also zero eax, since it will be `-EFAULT` after the SYSCALL.

---

Anyway, your asm is equivalent to this non-useful code:

```
int main(void) {
    const char *p = "/bin/sh";
    execve(p, &p, NULL);
}
```

note that  `push %rsp; pop %rsi` is equivalent to `mov %rsp, %rsi`.  So RSI holds a pointer to the stack memory where CALL wrote the "return address".

One more POP after that dereferences the stack pointer and loads the pointer to the string into RDI.

Using CALL to push the address of a string is really nasty.  IDK why you'd do that.  Just use MOV like a normal person.

---

**How to do this correctly**

```
# build with gcc -no-pie -g shell.S

#include <asm/unistd.h>         // for __NR_execve                                                                                                                
// #include <sys/syscall.h>     // or include this glibc header for SYS_execve

main:          # main(argc, argv, envp)
    mov   $shell, %edi     # filename = shell
                           # argv     = main's argv, already in rsi (not on the stack like in _start)

    # leave RDX = envp
    # xor   %edx, %edx       # envp     = NULL

    mov   $__NR_execve, %eax    # execve
    syscall                     # execve(shell, argv, envp)
    ret                    # in case the syscall fails

.section .rodata
shell:
.string "/bin/sh"
```

This works, and doesn't do anything weird.

---

**Or, in a way that works as a position-independent flat binary**, and doesn't use main()'s argv, since you added that request:

```
#include <asm/unistd.h>         // for __NR_execve                                                                                                                
// #include <sys/syscall.h>     // or include this glibc header for SYS_execve

.globl main
main:
    lea   shell(%rip), %rdi     # filename = shell
    xor   %edx, %edx            # envp     = NULL

    push  %rdx                  # or push $0
    push  %rdi
    mov   %rsp, %rsi            # argv     = { $shell, NULL } that we just pushed

    mov   $__NR_execve, %eax    # execve(
    syscall
    ret                    # in case the syscall fails
shell:                     # still part of the .text section, and we don't use the absolute address of the label, only for a RIP-relative LEA.
.string "/bin/sh"
```

Your RSI=RSP idea is not bad, but you forgot to add a terminating NULL pointer to the end of the `argv[]` array.

Outside of `main` which gets `envp[]` as an arg, we don't have an already-constructed `envp[]` accessible anywhere convenient, so just pass NULL.  On Linux, that's equivalent to passing a valid pointer to an empty NULL-terminated array, i.e. a pointer to an 8-byte `0` in memory.

Comment: I believe he's writing shell code so he won't want to use fixed sections and absolute addresses like your example. His string was placed within the code so that he could retrieve the address of the string by popping off the return address into _RDI_ . His method is a variation of the JMP/CALL/POP method. The idea is to run this code from an executable stack.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I wondered about that, but the OP never actually said that.  Putting the string right after or before main (in the .text section) would make a single block of PIC code with a RIP-relative LEA: `lea $shell(%rip), %rdi` instead of `mov $shell, %edi`.  The original obviously isn't trying to avoid `\0` bytes or anything, so my answer was aimed at teaching basic debugging with strace.

Comment: Actually when I saw the title of the question first thing I assumed it was likely a shell code question. When I saw the string in the code and the way he popped the return address as an argument it pretty much screams "shell code". As for RIP addressing, sure but your original code didn't do that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Well yeah, I thought it was going to be an exploit question, but then it was just a really basic `main()`, maybe from someone that's trying to learn asm from exploit tutorials instead of normal stuff.  I mean, the `push %rsp` made me think that the OP might not understand what the point of the CALL stuff was.  I think you're probably right, though, that the CALL/POP is a clue that this is baby steps towards shellcode, and might be what the OP wants (but failed to mention).

Comment: Thus the reason that I asked the OP for clarification 20 minutes ago in my comment under the question.

Comment: Looks like though from the OPs question history most of his recent questions are regarding exploits and shell code. I think we can safely say that what he was doing was intentional.

Comment: I know I can do like that. But when I translate assembly to shell code then it's impossible with using `shell: .string "/bin/sh"` like this. So I tried like that.

Comment: @user4929293: You could just put the label in the same section as the code, and use a relative LEA like I talked about in comments with Michael.  Updated my answer with a way that works as position-independent flat binary (e.g. shell code).  If you have weird requirements like that, you should mention them in your question.

Comment: It's my first time to study asm. So I didn't notify it was weird method

Comment: @user4929293: apparently using CALL to push a string address and jump over it is a common technique in exploit coding.  In 32-bit code, there is no RIP-relative addressing, so you can't use LEA that way.  That makes CALL an obvious choice.  Also, the LEA will have some zero-bytes in it (since the relative displacement is always 4 bytes), and many shellcode strings need to avoid zero-bytes.  But since you didn't specify any of these requirements in your code, I used the much-easier-to-understand way with LEA.

Comment: @Zibri: if you aren't in `main`, like in shellcode, you don't have an `envp` easily accessible anywhere without linker support.  But sure, I'll change the `main` example to pass through `envp`, even though the OP wasn't doing that.

Comment: Never mind I did it. It's very simple.
I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

C code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE             /* See feature_test_macros(7) */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **env)
{
  argv[0] = "/bin/bash";
  return execve(argv[0], argv, env);
}
```

64 bit X86 assembly code:

```
// gcc shell.S -Wl,--build-id=none -static -nostdlib -fPIC -o shell
// strip -s shell

#include <asm/unistd.h>

        .global _start

        .text
_start:
        mov (%rsp), %rbx        # rbx = argc

        mov     $__NR_execve, %rax             # system call 3b is execve()
        lea     sh(%rip), %rdi     # command to execute
        lea 8(%rsp), %rsi       # argv
#        xor     %rsi, %rsi              # no args
        lea 16(%rsp, %rbx, 8), %rdx # envp !!!
#        xor     %rdx, %rdx              # no envp
        syscall                         # invoke system call

        # exit(0)
        mov     $__NR_exit, %rax               # system call 60 is exit
        xor     %rdi, %rdi              # we want return code 0
        syscall                         # invoke operating system to exit
sh:
        .string  "/bin/bash"
```

you can invoke the shell as:

```
./shell
```

or

```
./shell -c "echo hello;echo world"
```

With this code all parameters of the command "shell" will be passed to /bin/bash unchanged.

Also the process name will change and become "bash" (in ps -ef)

And what is more important (which I didn't see anywhere else)

is that with this code the environment is preserved. (no pun intended)

If you don't need the args and you don't want the env preserved, uncomment the comments and comment the previous lines.

Comment: The question is tagged `[shellcode]`, so the OP wants a snippet of code that can be injected as an exploit payload.  That's why they don't want it to depend on `main`'s args or the `_start` stack layout.  You've written a good answer to a different question, e.g. [How Get arguments value using inline assembly in C without Glibc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/50260855) or others about writing your own `_start` (normally that calls `main`).  OTOH, the question itself doesn't really say that, so I upvoted your answer because it's potentially useful to someone that gets here from a search.

Comment: Both of our answers are not viable as shellcode because they use a positive `rel32` for a RIP-relative LEA, which will contain zeros in the upper bytes.  That can be solved with a `jmp` over the string so the `rel32` is negative, or with tricks like using an arbitrary offset for the LEA and then fixup with `sub` or `add`. [Avoiding 0xFF bytes in shellcode using CALL to read RIP?](//stackoverflow.com/a/55783375)

Comment: the OP didn't ask for non-zero code. and I didn't even include setuid/setgid because it was not in the question.